# why does clean_password2() method work but not clean_password1() in Django usercreationform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users, django-validation

I am trying to figure out why this works if someone could maybe explain it to me.

I've just created a custom user model (shown below) and for the password validation it uses the `clean_password2(self):` (shown below) method however when I try to use `clean_password1(self):` (shown below) the validation does not work. why? Surely using either `password1` or `password2` to clean the data would work since they are the same?

Django docs state that we can use `clean_<fieldname>():` methods to clean/validate data and since `password1` is a fieldname in my mind that should work.

#### Custom user model

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email Address", max_length=255, unique=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

#### This works

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Confirm Password",
        help_text="Enter the same password as before for validation",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["email"]
    

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

#### This doesn't

```
def clean_password1(self):
   # Check that the two password entries match
   password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
   password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

   if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
      raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
   return password1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: don't reference other fields in `clean_<fieldname>` methods.  Do this logic in the `clean` method instead.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

The why goes deep into Django forms.  The method that calls `clean_<fieldname>` is the following:

```
def _clean_fields(self):
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        # value_from_datadict() gets the data from the data dictionaries.
        # Each widget type knows how to retrieve its own data, because some
        # widgets split data over several HTML fields.
        if field.disabled:
            value = self.get_initial_for_field(field, name)
        else:
            value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
        try:
            if isinstance(field, FileField):
                initial = self.get_initial_for_field(field, name)
                value = field.clean(value, initial)
            else:
                value = field.clean(value)
            self.cleaned_data[name] = value
            if hasattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name):
                value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
                self.cleaned_data[name] = value
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.add_error(name, e)
```

In `_clean_fields`, each field is resolved in the order they appear on the form, and this is the first time `cleaned_data` is filled in for that field.  Because `password1` comes before `password2` in the fields list, when `clean_password1` is run, `cleaned_data["password2"]` has not yet been set.  Here is what happens to your code (I added comments):

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    # `"password2"` is not present in cleaned_data, so `password2` is set to None
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

    # With `password2 == None`, this condition resolves to false 
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
    # `password1` is returned without any validation error
    return password1
```

The reason `clean_password2` works is because `password2` comes later in the field list.